# Firefox is changing my code?

Tags: jquery, firefox, cross-browser

Here is the same .js file read by chrome and firefox...(latest versions)
can anyone see the difference? the firefox change the 'fadeTo' into 'fadeOut' and 'fadeIn'
The original script i wrote is fadeTo
Why is this happening?

Firefox:

```
$('document').ready(function(){
$('#errors').css('display', 'none');
$('#errors').fadeIn('fast');

if ($('#errors').length){
    $('#content').fadeOut('slow');
}
$('#container').click(function(){ 
$('#errors').fadeOut('slow'); 
$('#content').fadeIn('fast');
});


});
```

Chrome:

```
$('document').ready(function(){
$('#errors').css('display', 'none');
$('#errors').fadeIn('slow');

if ($('#errors').length){
$('#content').fadeTo('slow', 0.5);
}

$('#container').click(function(){ 
$('#errors').fadeOut('fest'); 
$('#content').fadeTo('slow', 1.0);
});

});
```

Comment: Does your original file look like the Chrome version?

Comment: it apparently also changed 'slow' to 'fast', 'fest' to 'slow', among other things... are you sure it's not a cached version or something?

Comment: Are these code snippets what's being seen in the respective developer tools for each browser? What does your source code look like?

Comment: How are you viewing the code in those browsers?

Comment: You forgot to just press ctrl-F5 and clear the cached files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd bet good money caching is to blame.  One browser is caching an old copy of this file.  Clear your cache in both browsers and refresh.  Or try a shift-refresh.